# How to create files in working folder on Windows 10 UWP

Tags: windows, file, security, uwp

We have a Universal Windows 10 Platform (UWP) application containing an unmodifiable C library which creates web files in its working folder. These web files are then loaded by the WebView object for display. This architecture is working fine on other platforms, but it fails on UWP due to a lack of write access to the working folder. Apparently in a UWP app the working folder has special ACL protections which prevent creating files. Is there a way to create a UWP app which is permitted to create new files in its own working folder?

Note, we have tried using a different folder but in those cases the WebView object either will not load a file at all or does not load associated xsl, css, etc files. Very frustrating.

Cheers, Bill  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to write to the installation folder. This is by design to ensure seamless differential updates and clean uninstall of apps.

Have you tried setting the current working directory (to local appdata for example) before using the component?

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, we have tried appdata and local-stream. When using appdata the C library can write its files to that folder, but the WebView will not follow the HTML linked files such as JS and CSS. When using local-stream the customer (us) has to write their own URI resolver class to load local files.  I did that and it both loads files from a writeable local folder and follows links to JS and CSS.  But it does not work with XML with XSL stylesheets. So all 3 (appx-web, appdata, and local-stream) fail for us and that's why we ask here for ideas. All suggestions welcome.

Comment: You may want to articulate a new question on how to get the webview to properly load content from the appdata location. The way the question is currently phrased, the answer is simply: no, you can't write there. A new question with the right tags and keywords will provide better visibility on your issue. Thanks!